# Highcharts - where to place style and changing style for one wedge in a pie chart

Tags: css, styles, highcharts, pie-chart

I have a Highcharts pie chart here: http://jsfiddle.net/6PbbR/52/

```
$(function () {

    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Radialize the colors
    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
        return {
            radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
            stops: [
                [0, color]
            ]
        };
    });

    // Build the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                shadow: true,
                    },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ""
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    size:'68%',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    shadow: true,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        distance: -40,
                        style: {
                        width: '100px'
                    },
                        color: '#fff',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b style="font-family:arial;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold">'+ this.point.name +'</b> ';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                 name: 'Income Investments',
                data: [
                     ['FLOATING RATE FUNDS',   16.667],
                    {
                        name: 'Corporate Capital Trust',
                        y: 16.667,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },                                     
                    ['BONDS',   16.667],
                    ['ANNUITIES',       16.667],
                    ['REITs',    16.667],
                    ['CDs',     16.667]
                ]
            }],

        colors: [
                     '#83a3c6',
                      '#98012e', 
                    '#19699b', 
                    '#ae9e8e', 
                    '#5283b0', 
                    '#958370'
                      ],
        });
    });

});
```

Two questions:

1) I'm not happy with how I inserted inline style in plotOptions{pie{formatter. Where is a better place to do this using the API, instead of brute-forcing inline style?

2) I would like to change the font-family for the red wedge (and possibly tweak fix its positioning/margins). What's the best way of doing this?

Edit: Ideally, I can accomplish my needs without needing to go outside the above function. Is it possible to attach style to just one data point using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple html, so you can add a `class` or `id` and then style using `css`.

js

```
formatter: function() {
    return '<b id="myTooltipId">'+ this.point.name +'</b> ';
}
```

css

```
#myTooltipId {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

**Update**:

Inside formatter you can get the slice properties using `this`.
So you just have to check if the slice is the one you want.

```
formatter: function() {
    // key is the slice name
    if (this.key == 'CDs') {
        return '<b id="myTooltipId">'+ this.point.name +'</b> ';
    } else {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can modify this to work by generating a unique ID for each pie wedge. That way, I can change the fonts for just one wedge, and not all of them.

I have to pass this off to another developer and I have to hope they'll properly add the css to their sheet. So, I'd rather do it all within the API, but I'm not sure I can attach style to just one data point. I guess that's my real question.